# SSH not connecting to the machine (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a problem with one machine, the machine is running, the server that is on it also works, but I can not report to ssh and files, I have the entire server server there

[image]

When it tries to connect, it pops up:
SSH:

[image]

After clicking connect without proxy, this is displayed:

[image]

FileZilla:

[image]

Anyone know how to solve it, someone was supposed to?
I am asking here because I have already tested some google solutions but they did not help, in addition, the google support is so great that there is even no contact with them.
I hope that someone knows it, because I care about the files that are there, or if it is impossible to recover, so to speak, this machine, maybe there is a chance to recover the files?

Answer (score 0):

The connection to your local machine via SSH might not be allowed due to the firewall setup in your GCP account.

[Connecting Securely to GCP](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/connecting-securely) will help you to troubleshoot the SSH port issues with the network security section.

For more quicker solution, simply get to the VPC Firewall section and open the VPC that's associated with your VM. Check if the SSH port 22 is allowed in the VPC. It should be incoming. If it's allowed there, then SSH should work from external IP. More info available here - [VPC Firewalls in GCP](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls).

Comment: Please share the error screen shot in English Language to proceed further investigation.

Comment: is still the same problem as before when the firewall was added
https://imgur.com/a/6Ora6l9